# Accessing Request Context Value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I pass language code from client side as part of header "Accept-Language" which I want to access from Java(Spring Boot - REST) and set it in the Request Context kind of option to access the variable any where across the application for that particular context.

I'm trying with filter class where set the value in Request Context object but it is not working out the way I want. What is the best option for this?

Comment: Are you trying to use same the lang code for all the subsequent request as well?

Comment: No, it might change (when user switch from one language to other).

Comment: Why are you creating your own? This is supported out-of-the-box. You only need to register the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` to your Spring boot configuration (to override the default added `FixedLocaleResolver`). and be done. You can then inject the `Locale` in your controllers or use the `LocaleContextHolder` to obtain the `Locale`. Work with the framework instead of around the framework.

Comment: I'm able to get Locale as parameter in the controller, but then to use them in Service layer I have pass that as a parameter. I thought if there is an elegant way to access it where ever I want rater than passing it through out.

Comment: LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();, LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(); does the trick.

Comment: @syv Provide you code